# Computing the GCD

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

So I was given multiple questions of computing the GCD of $\gcd(10;45)$ and $\gcd(1701;3768)$, etc. The questions generally worked with numbers and I was able to solve it quite simply since I knew what would be $q$ and $r$ but I was given a question with variables that says compute the gcd of  $$\gcd(7a,7^2b)$$

and i'm completely confused on how to go about it.

Comment: The only thing you can say is it is $7gcd(a,7b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One basic rule is that,
if $d$ is the gcd
of $a$ and $b$,
then
$d$ divides
$ua-vb$
for any integers
$u$ and $v$.

Another basic rule is that,
if $d$ is the gcd
of $a$ and $b$,
and $c$ divides both
$a$ and $b$,
then
$c$ divides $d$
and
$d/c = \gcd(a/c, b/c)
$.

For
$d = \gcd(7a,7^2b)$,
note that,
since $7$
divides both terms,
$7$ must divide $d$.

So, let
$d_1 = d/7$.
Dividing out the $7$
on both sides,
$d_1 = \gcd(a, 7b)$.

Since we don't know anything about
$a$ and $b$,
we can't go any further.

Therefore
$d = 7d_1
= 7 \gcd(a, 7b)
$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for the explanation along with the solution, this made it much more clear.